# CaptureActivity Changes Locale of the application(zxing barcode scanner)

Tags: java, android, localization, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm  developing a multi-lang app which lets the user choose the preferred language from the setting menu.It works fine everywhere.But something which is the problem is that I integrated **zxing** in my applications as an standalone barcode scanner,So I'll be able to change the string resource values for different languages,but when I start the CaptureActivity,the **locale** changes to English in my application,So I have to relaunch the app to have the previous saved language.I couldn't find out the problem,please help me solve this issue.
The link for integration process is the following:

[Integrating ZXing in your Android App as standalone scanner](http://blog.dihaw.com/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/)

Any hints will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the current locale using SharedPreferences or any other method... and check the locale and apply it at the starting of every activity and its onResume method...

Comment: I'd used SharedPreferences but I didn't change the locale in the onResume method,Thanks for your answer.It works.

Comment: Sorry,but would you please tell me why the provided solution does not work for all activities?I mean I have the setting activity and language setting activity ,after changing the language and returning to Setting,in spite of calling "SetLocale()" in the onResume  of Setting activity,the language does not being changed!

Comment: You mean for each activity in the onResume method I set the locale and start itself again via startactivity??

Comment: I know it does not work!!please tell me exactly where to restart the activity?

Comment: no... I didnt mean that... When u change the locale you have to restart the whole application.. For ex: if you are changing the locale from a settings activity, after changing the locale you have to restart the app itself...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98634/discussion-between-rishad-appat-and-developer-account).